# Terminal Server 2008 RemoteApp sometimes multiple windows pop under other windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal, remoteapp

We are running a 3rd party ERP system button bar that launches various business modules.  Some of these modules have controls that launch separate windows.  All of that works great.  However on occasion, when someone opens some of these additional windows, the target window ends up behind another window and they get stuck trying to activate the target window.

Is there a tweak, adjustment, fix, known issue, etc that addresses this to help provide better control over multiple windows to allow users better control over which is the active window?

Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: I tried this hotfix but it didn't work: 

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967885

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using RemoteApp and NOT citrix, but citrix has a similar bug and a fix in the registry (again citrix specific) however, you may find a similar fix for RemoteApp -- http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101644

> Set: Registry Key: KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Citrix/wfshell/TWI
>
> Value Name: SeamlessFlags
>
> Value Type: REG_DWORD
>
> Value: 0x8000